# Content not Showing in production works well in development Material ui Pricing example

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use material-ui for React JS and creating this pricing page.
The thing is that it is working properly in development when I deployed the site the cards are not visible
Below is my code For Pricing page:
I use "useEffect()" in order to check whether data is actually coming or not, consoling shows that data is coming

Development version=>[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1beU.png
Production build => [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc8XY.png

````
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import StarIcon from "@material-ui/icons/StarBorder";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  "@global": {
    ul: {
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
      listStyle: "none",
    },
  },
  link: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1, 1.5),
  },
  heroContent: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: "8px",
    elevation: 10,
    padding: "20px",
    height: "100%",
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
  },
  cardHeader: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
  },
  cardPricing: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "baseline",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  footer: {
    borderTop: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(6),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(6),
    },
  },
}));

const tiers = [
  {
    title: "Free",
    price: "0",
    description: ["1 user included", "10 Contracts"],
    buttonText: "Current Plan",
    buttonVariant: "outlined",
  },
  {
    title: "Starter",
    subheader: "Most popular",
    price: "19",
    description: ["3 users included", "200 Contracts"],
    buttonText: "Upgrade",
    buttonVariant: "outlined",
  },
  {
    title: "Business",
    price: "99",
    description: ["10 users included", "1000 Contracts"],
    buttonText: "Upgrade",
    buttonVariant: "outlined",
  },
  {
    title: "Enterprise",
    price: "199",
    description: ["25 users included", "5000 Contracts"],
    buttonText: "Upgrade",
    buttonVariant: "outlined",
  },
];

export default function Upgrade() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tiers);
  }, []);
  return (
    <Container className={classes.heroContent}>
      <Container>
        <Typography
          component="h1"
          variant="h3"
          align="center"
          color="textPrimary"
          gutterBottom
        >
          Pricing
        </Typography>
        <Typography
          variant="h5"
          align="center"
          color="textSecondary"
          component="p"
        >
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis est
          eos laudantium nobis quasi accusamus, commodi dignissimos perspiciatis
          voluptate unde, recusandae voluptatum nostrum, inventore impedit iste
          aut natus ea eaque.
        </Typography>
      </Container>
      <Divider style={{ margin: "20px 0" }} />
      {/* </Container>
      <Container maxWidth="md" component="main"> */}
      <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="flex-end">
        {tiers.map((tier) => (
          // Enterprise card is full width at sm breakpoint
          <Grid
            item
            key={tier.title}
            xs={12}
            //sm={tier.title === "Enterprise" ? 12 : 6}
            sm={12}
            md={3}
          >
            <Card>
              <CardHeader
                classes={classes.Estitle}
                title={tier.title}
                subheader={tier.subheader}
                titleTypographyProps={{ align: "center" }}
                subheaderTypographyProps={{ align: "center" }}
                action={tier.title === "Starter" ? <StarIcon /> : null}
                className={classes.cardHeader}
              />
              <CardContent>
                <div className={classes.cardPricing}>
                  <Typography component="h2" variant="h3" color="textPrimary">
                    ${tier.price}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="h6" color="textSecondary">
                    /mo
                  </Typography>
                </div>
                <ul>
                  {tier.description.map((line) => (
                    <Typography
                      component="li"
                      variant="subtitle1"
                      align="center"
                      key={line}
                    >
                      {line}
                    </Typography>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions>
                <Button fullWidth variant={tier.buttonVariant} color="primary">
                  {tier.buttonText}
                </Button>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
[![Below is the developement version][1]][1]```


[![Production build][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1beU.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc8XY.png
````

Comment: Development version=>[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1beU.png
  Production build => [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc8XY.png

Comment: weird thing, check that build in serve package

Comment: @NishargShah did that also problem still persist..!

Comment: Got the answer the problem was with this comment
// Enterprise card is full width at sm breakpoint
when i remove this it works perfectly.!